# How can I use this welder with 16A/230V two pin plug in the UK?

Tags: wiring, uk, cord-and-plug, welding

I bought a Sherman™ DIGITIG 200GD from Amazon a month ago, sadly it came with a European 16A/230V two pin plug.

I've been so focused on making sure to meet stringent safety measures for my humble "workshop" that this slipped me by.

I am not knowledgeable in electrical matters, I would like to know how can I power this machine? I was expecting to get a 3 pin UK plug

I trust it’s not as simple as getting a shaving plug adapter. Is there a tool on the market that, in particular, welders rely on to convert 2 pin plugs to 3 pin plugs?

I also need to buy a 10 meter, 16A extension lead as well, if this converter exists in the form of a long cable it would be perfect

The plug:

[image]

Comment: Electrically, 230V is 230V. You should be able to cut the end off the cord and put a new one on. I'd pair that with an extension cord. You haven't shown a picture of the plug that the welder came with, but I'd be shocked (sorry) if a device with a metal case didn't come with a grounded plug. If that is the case, I would consider swapping out the whole power cord and plug to one that includes a ground wire. You would then connect the ground wire to the frame inside the welder.

Comment: You don't run a 16A machine on a 13A plug. Get an electrician to install a dedicated supply with isolator to run that welder.

Comment: Can you add picture/s of the plug.  According to amazon UK it has a UK/Europe standard two pin plug, but comes with a three pin adapter.  Standard American welder plugs are two blades and ground pin prong.

Comment: @SolarMike You can run a 16A machine on a 13A plug no trouble.  (Particularly if you are not going to be running it unattended.)

Comment: @Drew If the machine came with a 2-pin plug, it is very unlikely to have any use for a ground connection.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica yes, sorted a welder on a farm that used a 1/4" bolt in place of a 13A fuse. So that’s not **my** game.

Comment: @SolarMike wow, they recklessly overfused that. Should have used a 3/16" bolt! :)

Comment: I have never seen a 2 pin 16amp plug in the USA. The only possibility would be a 120v  15 or 20 amp plug going to a double insulated tool.  This welder sounds like it would not be legal for use in the US / commercial it may be fine for the UK, how about posting a clear photo of the plug, @ Martin  boner in the U.S. you could not run a 16 amp machine on a 13 amp plug for 2 reasons it would be a code violation and they don’t make 13 or 16 amp plugs in the US 15 & 20 but a 20 would not fit in a 15.

Comment: From what I've been able to dig up, the Sherman DIGITIG is not an American machine but a Polish welder intended for use in continental Europe.  The plug pictured is a standard Type E plug - 2 pins with Earth on a sleeve/collar.  You should just need a pin adapter to plug into a UK socket since voltage and frequency are the same.

Comment: That looks like a regular European Schuko plug, not an American one. (But it's hard to tell from just the surface of the plug.)

Comment: @ChrisO I think you are right. I was going over the manual yesterday and it was mix of English and what looked to be polish (I think). I have provied a picture in my OP. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not an American plug.  It's a combined French/German plug, with live and neutral pins, and an earth contact too.

Don't even think of trying to plug it into a shaver adaptor.  They are limited to a maximum of 1A, and can't possibly handle a welder.  And don't use any of the dodgy "universal" travel adaptors either.  They are potentially dangerous, and won't make contact with the Earth on that plug.

You could try fitting a 13A plug.  Unfortunately, the manual does not say whether this will work, or whether it will keep blowing the fuse in the plug.  It says that it needs to be on a 25A protected circuit, even though the plug is only rated for a constant 16A.

A better solution would be a blue 16A "Commando" (also known as "CEEform") plug.  But that requires a matching socket to plug it into.

Comment: Hey, thaks allot for looking into this! I consulted an alectrician and passed your answer to him and he agreed. Am up and running thanks!